# Animating QPushButton PyQt

Tags: animation, pyqt, qpushbutton, qpropertyanimation

I'm having an issue trying to animate a QPushButtons. I've a queue of buttons that once popped, I would like to animate from one color to another. I've recreated a minimum working example below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget

from main import comboBox

app = QApplication([])
app.setStyle('Fusion')
window = QWidget()

def change_color():
    anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(changeButton, b"color")
    anim.setDuration(1000)
    anim.setStartValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 144, 0))
    anim.setEndValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    anim.start()


hbox = QHBoxLayout()
hbox.addStretch(1)
changeButton = QPushButton()
changeButton.setText("change Grid")
hbox.addWidget((changeButton))
window.setLayout((hbox))


window.show()
app.exec()

changeButton.clicked.connect(lambda event: change_color())
```

When I go into the debug mode it shows that it's reaching each of the lines, however, it there is no color change happening. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I've updated it with an MRE

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

The first is that you're connecting the signal *after* the `app.exec()` call. That call starts the event loop, and, as such, it's blocking (nothing after that line will be processed until it returns), so you must move that *before* starting the event loop.

Then, as the [QPropertyAnimation documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html#details):

> QPropertyAnimation interpolates over Qt **properties**.

`color` is not a Qt property for QPushButton (nor any of its base classes), in fact, if you look at the debug/terminal output for your program (after moving the signal connection as said above), you'll see the following:

`StdErr: QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property color of your QObject`

A simple solution would be to use [QVariantAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) instead, and update the color in a function connected to the animation's [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html#valueChanged) signal.

```py
def change_color():
    def updateColor(color):
        # ... change the color

    anim = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(changeButton)
    anim.setDuration(1000)
    anim.setStartValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 144, 0))
    anim.setEndValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    anim.valueChanged.connect(updateColor)
    anim.start()

# ...

changeButton.clicked.connect(change_color)
```

The choice becomes the way you change color: **if** you're not using stylesheets for the button, the more appropriate way would be to use the button palette:

```py
def change_color(button):
    def updateColor(color):
        palette.setColor(role, color)
        button.setPalette(palette)
    palette = button.palette()
    role = button.foregroundRole()
    anim = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(button)
    anim.setDuration(1000)
    anim.setStartValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 144, 0))
    anim.setEndValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    anim.valueChanged.connect(updateColor)
    anim.start(anim.DeleteWhenStopped)

# ...

changeButton.clicked.connect(lambda: change_color(changeButton))
```

Note that I added the button argument (you should not use globals anyway), and also the `DeleteWhenStopped` flag to `start()` in order to avoid unnecessary stacking of unused animations when they're finished.

If, instead, you're using stylesheets, you need to override the button's stylesheet. Obviously, you have to be careful: the button shouldn't have any stylesheet set directly on it.

```py
def change_color(button):
    def updateColor(color):
        button.setStyleSheet('color: {}'.format(color.name()))
    # ...
```

Note that a more appropriate approach would be to subclass the button and implement the animation directly on it. By doing that you *can* use a QPropertyAnimation by using a custom `pyqtProperty`, but you will still need to manually set the color as above in the property setter. In this case, you can just have a single animation (possibly creating it in the `__init__`) and just update its start/end values.

Alternatively, you can just call `update` in the setter, and override the `paintEvent()` by using QStyle functions to draw the button primitive and label using the property value.